# Fetching unmatched substrings from almost same Strings using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I'm having a REST document containing a list of URL formats.

```
/com/shop/product/{product_id}
/com/shop/{shop_id}
/com/city/{city_name}/shop/{shop_id}/details
```

etc..


And the dynamic URLs look something like below

```
/com/shop/product/0ab12h
/com/shop/j8khdj
/com/city/bangalore/shop/78hj67/details
```

My input will be a dynamic URL.
 And on passing of any of the dynamic URL, I want to find the matched documented URL along with the mapping of dynamic values and the fields marked in curly braces.

Like for 
`/com/city/bangalore/shop/78hj67/details`   the matched URL is
`/com/city/{city_name}/shop/{shop_id}/details`

And the map should be

```
city_name -> bangalore
shop_id -> 78hj67
```

I was able to achieve it with normal string operations. But I want to do it with REGEX. 
Can it be achieved ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Show what you currently have and what needs changing

Comment: Earlier I was splitting up the dynamic url using '/'.  And i was getting all the substrings which includes dynamic values also.  And I was iterating through the documenter URLs. I'm splitting and collecting the substrings again.  Then while comparing i'm getting matched URL along with the mapped fields.

Comment: Show that code in the question. The objective of this site is to help you fix **your code** not write it from scratch. Also if your code works it might be better to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl My intention was not to get a free service. i'm trying it parallely for the solution. As i'm not confident with regex, asked for the opinion here. thanks

Comment: But you still need to show the relevant code ... otherwise it may not be your intention but with nothing to start from then that's what is currently expected

Answer (score 1):

Solving this with regex is not particularly hard.

For your above example you could use: [`(?:city\/)(\w+)(?:\/shop\/)(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/q0neB8/2)
and find the answers in match group 1 and 2 (follow the link in the pattern to get an in-depth explanation of the pattern).

```
const regex = /(?:city\/)(\w+)(?:\/shop\/)(\w+)/g;
const str = `/com/city/bangalore/shop/78hj67/details `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Since you seem to require different portions of the dynamic URLs you are likely not able to come up with a single regex that does everything for you. Instead, you are forced to write multiple patterns, which is probably not any better than using normal string operations.

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach suggested in above answer. 
Normally we match a list of strings using one regex. 
But here its in reverse, Each documented URL is a regex, and It need to be matched with the dynamic URL.
So in a loop of iteration,
 a documented URL will get picked one by one and converted in to regex.

```
     // As fields inside curly braces can contain special characters
     // using /\{[^}]+\}/g as regex 
     // As dynamic URL won't contain special chars replacing it with (\w+)
     // Using () to group the dynamic fields

     var regexUrl = docUrl.replace(/\{[^}]+\}/g, "(\\w+)");
     regexUrl = "^" + regexUrl + "$";
     var res = dynUrl.match(regexUrl);
```

If regex matches the pattern, `res` will contain **dynamic values** of the URL.

```
     // Fetching dynamic fields from URL
     var dynFields = docUrl.match(/\{[^}]+\}/g);
```

Using `dynFields` and `res` we can have a map of dynamic fields and it's values.

Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jr9zx1xe/

This approach is more complex, I think String or trie based approach can be useful in reducing complexity.

Comment: Nice. Glad you could come up with an efficient solution.